Playwright can't logout and back in as a new user within a single test
I'm trying to use a model based test approach, integrating xstate with playwright. Our system uses a workflow where 2 users can log into the system and respond to each others actions to progress through the workflow.
When I try to log out and back in again using the same browser, the browser logs back in as the first user, as if it was unable to clear that authenticated session when I logged out and defaulted back to it even though I entered a different user's details
Adding an afterEach that fully closes the browser between tests seemed to be a solution to this for single login tests, as this would clear all cookies and I was able to get through to my second test, logged in as the second user, however this quickly failed again, as I was not closing the browser in between different logins between individual test steps.
The problem is I can't find a way to be able to control/reference the browser or open multiple browsers in the test model, as the browser instance is created later in the test hooks. I would like to find a way to be able to close and re open the browser window in between steps, ideally incorporating this into my log in/logout functions OR maybe i'm missing some step when I logout to clear the session properly and then log back in with a new user
Below are my hooks and then what xstate is using to run the tests and is at the bottom of my script
test.beforeEach(async ({ browser }) => {
  page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(URL);
  testNum++
});

test.afterEach(async ({browser}) => {
  for(let context of browser.contexts())
    await context.close()
});

test.describe('CE workflows', () => {
  const testPlans = testModel.getSimplePathPlans();

  testPlans.forEach((plan, i) => {
    plan.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
      test(path.description, async ({}) => {
        await path.test(page);
      });
    });
  });
})

These are the login/logout functions I bookend each test step with
async function login(email) {
  await page.goto(URL);
  await page.getByTestId('loginEmail').fill(email);
  await page.getByTestId('loginPassword').fill('password');
  await page.getByTestId('btnLogin').click();

  if (await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Allow cookies' }).isVisible())
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'No thanks' }).click();
}

async function logout() {
  await page.getByTestId('btnOptions').click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Logout' }).click();
}

This is the first edge in my model
Each step is similair to this in that it logs in, carries out the users action, then logs out, ready to be passed to the second user
const testModel = createModel(CEWorkflowMachine, {
  events: {
    CREATE_CE_CLIENT: async () => {
      await login()

      await page.goto(URL);
      await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Create compensation event' }).click();

      await page.getByLabel('Title').fill(`Test for model based CE ${testNum}`);
      await page.getByLabel('Description').fill('Test Description');
      await page.getByLabel('Project manager\'s assumptions').fill('Test Assumption');
      await page.getByText('The Project Manager gives an').click();

      await page.getByText('Notify').click();

      await logout()
    },


page = await browser.newPage();. Where is page defined? Does it have a let declaration? If it doesnt that is setting a global which is asking for trouble.

Please remove single backticks from your code.

There are few flags here which one of or multiple are likely leading to this behaviour. Ultimately, if it's logging in as the previous user, you are having issues with test isolation or some async/order of execution issue.
Confused test isolation
You currently do this to manage browser pages:
test.beforeEach(async ({ browser }) => {
  page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(URL);
  testNum++
})

This implies page is a variable available in scope. If it is not defined by let page, the situation would be worse as that would mean it's actually completely global.
Even if not global, it's asking for trouble to keep around a mutable reference. You'll have problems if you have in-file parallelisation or want to add that later. Add in that you can accidentally reference this var; or close over it with a closure; and factor in that lots of things are async and you can conclude this is highly risky and hellish to manage. Doing this is highly unusual and you won't see it in any official docs.
Whilst it's possible to have this and perfectly manage it, you are opening yourself up to a whole category of bugs that are now possible. page is attached to a browser context, and this is the construct playwright offers to isolate tests. If you have any chance of reusing it between tests at all there is a problem.
I strongly suspect this is probable in your case. The state machines are "closing over" the page variable you have setup. They may well  still be referencing that old page object reference even if you reassign page.
You should scrap this widely scoped page var completely. Instead, make sure you are using page as passed to the test handlers/hooks:
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(URL);
});

test.describe('CE workflows', () => {
  const testPlans = testModel.getSimplePathPlans();

  testPlans.forEach((plan, i) => {
    plan.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
      test(path.description, async ({page}) => {
        await path.test(page);
      });
    });
  });
})`

You shouldn't need the manual browser closing if your tests are correctly isolated. So I removed that. The page provided to the test methods (and hooks) had already been scoped to the relevant test automatically. Ensure this is passed through to any shared methods and you are not using a global or widely scoped page anywhere.
That means your state machines will need to be provided page. You need to actually use the page that was passed to the machine (which now is passed the right one from test()). Note this is how it's done in the official docs.
const testModel = createModel(CEWorkflowMachine, {
  events: {
    CREATE_CE_CLIENT: async (page) => {
      await login(page)

      await page.goto(URL);
      await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Create compensation event' }).click();

      await page.getByLabel('Title').fill(`Test for model based CE ${testNum}`);
      await page.getByLabel('Description').fill('Test Description');
      await page.getByLabel('Project manager\'s assumptions').fill('Test Assumption');
      await page.getByText('The Project Manager gives an').click();

      await page.getByText('Notify').click();

      await logout(page);
    }

And of course those login/logout methods need to accept page as a parameter and use that.
No need to call browser.newPage since the one provided to the tests/hooks is already a fresh one.
Logout not waiting
When you await a click() on the logout and login buttons, that will resolve as soon as the button is clicked. It won't automatically wait until the next page.
Your logon case is OK, because afterwards it of course waits to interact with the logged on page.
But for logout, depending on if the flow is complex or long, this means it clicks the logout button and immediately ends the test and kills the browser context. It's possible the logout did not have time to complete.
You can fix this by instructing Playwright to wait.
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(),
  page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Logout' }).click()
])

However, theoretically this should not matter, since the browser contexts should be different between tests. But if there's leakage, this could compound the issue.

Thank you for your answer, this sounds like it is along the right lines to solving my problem, I've fixed the logout function to wait for navigation no problem. I set up the before each as you have (I think I'd copied this from a forum post originally) and re arranged my model to be exactly as the docs, however all of my references to page within a step give an error that it is of type UNKNOWN, I have a decleration of  let page: Page at the top of the page but is this incorrect as you mentioned I should avoid declaring it globally, where should I define it instead

Yes its crucial we get rid of that variable. In this example https://xstate.js.org/docs/packages/xstate-test (pupeteer not playwright but thats irrelevant) go to steps 3/4. Xstate provides the one passed into path.test to callbacks throughout. The unknown complaint is just becasue you'll need to pass the type arg. It will actually be there and be the right thing i think, its just typing issue. Possibly try createMachine<Page> where Page is the TS type imported from playwright?

Or you could just try typing it by assigning the type right there on the callback paramater. Im less sure about this part to be honest. Im not sure how it works with xstate test lib. Requires more reading. Could be wrong about the type param thing.

Ok its detailed here https://xstate.js.org/docs/packages/xstate-test/#api. See "testContext". Theres no TS examples though. You could just type it by assigning the type directly on the param i guess.

Yeah you are right, when running it just ignores the type errors and everything works as expected. Interestingly, after some investigation, its actually both the login function and the logout function that are messing things up, with the steps Login  -> go to URL, the new URL is loading before the login has a chance to finish authenticating the new user and so it defaults to the previous one and the logout like you said was doing a similair thing. Thanks for your help!

That shouldnt be the case though. It is a sign something is wrong. All individual tests are supposed to have their own page, which playwright ensures has its own browser context. Browser contexts do not share cookies etc. This is to ensure test isolation. That a test can get the session of a "previous" user presumably that was logged onto by a previous test, proves your tests are not correctly isolated. You can fix the logout/login code for faux-isolation, but it wont fix the root cause here, which will come back to haunt you. The bug your seeing shouldn't even be possible  with isolation.

Sorry I think I should have been clearer in my original question, these logouts occur within the same test so they are using the same browser context. This is obviously not the case with the more component based testing but for these end to end models, using xstate, this is the way I've got it to work

Ah! Yeh that makes sense. Honestly, you should use separate tests and maintain isolation. It remains the case in E2E also that inter reliant assertions where some conceptual grouping is reliant on the previous being done, is error-prone. Fundamentally, this approach leads to high complexity and flakiness . You no longer get good feedback when they fail cos many fail at once. Take it from someone who's built way way too many enterprise e2e solutions (i am bored lol). This concept is harder on e2e, but achievable, and you should require it. It does not scale otherwise.

This is why separating tests in playwright also comes with all this sandboxing/context stuff. Thats by design, and not to be avoided. For the good of your sanity in a few years time, you should adopt it. If you must, use playwright api's to explicitly share certain things like maybe auth cookies (this is important, as opposed to implied ambiguous relationships). When it grows organically, and uncontrolled with no isolation, you end up with a suite that only passes when execution happens to fall down a very narrow code path, and otherwise just splashes red indescriminately.

Then you end up spending more time maintaining them than actually getting the value out of them.
